# Execute a Unix command with backticks from Java

Tags: java, unix, process

I am trying to execute the following command from java (runs properly in a unix box)-

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -i myScript.sh | grep bash | awk '{print $2}'`
```

But when executing via Java, I get following error-

```
/usr/bin/kill[8]: `ps: Arguments must be %job or process ids
Exit : 1
```

**Code:**

```
String command = "kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -i myScript.sh | grep bash | awk '{print $2}'`";
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
String error = null;
while((error = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(error);
}
exitVal = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exit : "+ exitVal);
```

p.s. - Just a reminder that the command runs perfectly fine under a shell.

Comment: backtick magic is done by the shell, and here you run the command kill without the shell, that's why backticks aren't evaluated.

Comment: You can separate it to `ps` and `kill` parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to run is a shell command line but you're running `kill` and passing it all the arguments which is why you're getting an error from `/usr/bin/kill`.

You should run a shell like `bash` from your Java code and then pass your command line in using the `-c` option.

If you're doing this it's probably a good idea to pass you command arguments in as an array rather than a single sting.

```
String[] command = {"bash","-c","kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -i myScript.sh | grep bash | awk '{print $2}'`"};
```

Comment: Dave..  I've passed my commands args as an array, and now, even though the process gets killed in the back-end, I got this error from the Java method - 
`/bin/bash: line 0: kill: (13507) - No such process
Exit2 : 9`

Comment: @kaustavdatta - Not sure what's happening. Sounds like the command is failing as `kill` can't find the process, but you say the command is being kill so I'm confused.  An alternative approach that would be easier to debug would be to run just `ps -ef` and use Java code find the appropriate PID from the output then then run `kill` passing it that PID.